# Visual Studio 2019 performance profiler error while collecting snapshots

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, memory-leaks

Trying to get started with Visual Studio 2019 Performance Profiler to find memory leaks in an ASP.NET Core Web API application.

So, I choose the "memory usage" checkbox from the list.

Taking snapshots works fine too but when I click on "stop collection" button, I get a popup alert as "No Managed Heap data was collected. This feature requires .NET v4.5 or greater".

I tried installing .NET 4.5 but I do have 4.8 (as the installer reports).

Any clue on how I could get this thing working?

I am also interested to explore free/open source memory profiler alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using IIS express to debug/profile.
For anyone facing this issue, use Kestrel(i.e. name of your application while choosing to debug profile).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be document %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll and %windir%\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll.
The file corresponding to the higher version could not be applied during the installation process, and it is still another lower version.

Comment: I just upgraded and restarted my machine from .net 4.8 to 4.8.1 dev pack and it's still the same issue.

Comment: FWIW, File version of %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll & %windir%\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll is 10.0.19041.1

Comment: Try to uninstall .net4.8, download again and restart, will the problem still occur?

Comment: I have upgraded the framework to 4.8.1 but still the same :(

Comment: You can repair it in the visual studio installer and see if the problem still occurs.